# Testing against a string/object

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON-encoded PHP array:

```
<script>
var registeredEmails = <?php echo(json_encode($emails)); ?>;
</script>
```

To check that this works, I do this:

```
console.log(registeredEmails);
// this outputs: ["john@domain.com", "mary@domain.com"]
```

And now I would like to iterate through that JSON and test a certain string against all the strings it contains.

```
for (var email in registeredEmails) {
    if (registeredEmails.hasOwnProperty(email)) {

        var duplicate = registeredEmails[email];

        console.log(duplicate + ' is typeof: ' + typeof(duplicate));
        // this outputs: john@domain.com is typeof: string

        //  $(this).val() is a string from somewhere else
        if (duplicate.test($(this).val())) {
            // we found a match
        };
    }
}
```

As I understand it, the `test()` method tests for matches on strings. I've tested to make sure that my variable `duplicate` is a string, but apparently it's still an object. I'm given the following JS error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object john@domain.com has no method 'test'
```

Why is that?

Comment: You may be looking for 'string.indexOf('stringToFind') !== -1` or `/regex pattern/.test(string)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is a method of the RegEx object, not String.

Your best bet would probably be to use [`String.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) instead. You could also probably use [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) if you're not trying to use Regular Expression matching.

Answer (score 1):

Although you are using json_encode your console output looks like an array to me. If that is the case then maybe you can use the following:

```
var found = find_match( registeredEmails, $(this).val() );

if( found ) {
   // found a match
}

function find_match(array, string) {

    for( var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len ; i++ ) {
        if( array[i].indexOf( string ) > -1 ) return true;
    }

    return false;
}​
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/3hbK6/1/)

Comment: That's what I thought too. What I have works, but thanks for answering. +1 in any case.